# How can I use the protected function _initProduct() from a custom module Block

Tags: product

I want to initialise simple products of a configurable one, by using the protected function (or another one), but I can't get the it in my code.

I have called in my class file:

```
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';
```

For info: my class are already extending anther class:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition as the action is protected you can only access that method from that class or classes which extend off it.  But, it really just boils down to a call to the`initProduct()` method of the `catalog/product` helper so your best bet is probably just to access this helper method directly passing it the correct arguments.  You do however need to pass it a controller object so it's only really feasible as part of a request to the product controller.

What is it you are hoping to achieve by running the `_initProduct()` method, I know you want to initialise simple products, but in order to do what?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It's in order the update the stock via Webservice call, and that's done threw an event observer :
catalog_controller_product_init_before

Comment: Any reason why you can't just load the product, edit the stock and then save it?